# Xamarin can't build apk

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I updated VS and Xamarin last week. No I have this shiny new ArchiveManager. Unfortunately I'm no longer able to build apk's with it. I can build it without errors, but when I try to Archive my solution it failes with this error message in the output:

```
The "BuildApk" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'obj\Release\android\bin\packaged_resources-armeabi-v7a'.
File name: 'obj\Release\android\bin\packaged_resources-armeabi-v7a'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.ExecuteWithAbi(String supportedAbis, String apkInputPath, String apkOutputPath)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

When I remove the armeabi-v7a it does just the same with x86 etc.

I tried the SDK Tools of Android 6 and 7 but both have the same error.

What's wrong here?

Comment: having similar issues. need the .apk file to run my UITests on android but, its not in the debug/bin.

Comment: NPardrutt, can you confirm you version information? I tried with XVS 4.2.0.695, Build Tools 24.0.3, SDK Tools 25.2.2, Platform Tools 24.0.3. @user1232726, If you use the Archive Manager successfully, you can Distribute and use AdHoc to get an APK. Otherwise, run on a device/emulator first, then the bin will have an .apk.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.
You can check if your SDK manager to see if the system image (armeabi-v7a) is installed or not. 
Then try to select **only 1** architecture (like armeabi-v7a) and recompile.